# Building Poco 1.9.0 with Crypto module

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang, poco-libraries

I need to build Poco 1.9.0 with clang for Android armeabi-v7a.

I build it like this:

```
./configure --no-sharedmemory --no-wstring --config=Android-armeabi-v7a-clang --no-samples --no-tests --omit=Data,PageCompiler,ApacheConnector,CppParser,PDF,PocoDoc,ProGen,Encodings,CppUnit,MongoDB,Redis,SevenZip,Zip
make -j4
make install
```

Here is configuration file for Android-armeabi-v7a-clang I have created:

```
#
# $Id: //poco/1.4/build/config/Android#3 $
#
# Android
#
# Make settings for Android NDK
#

#
# General Settings
#
LINKMODE           ?= STATIC
ANDROID_ABI        ?= armeabi-v7a
POCO_TARGET_OSNAME  = Android
POCO_TARGET_OSARCH  = $(ANDROID_ABI)

ifeq ($(ANDROID_ABI),armeabi)
TOOL      = arm-linux-androideabi
ARCHFLAGS = -mthumb
else
ifeq ($(ANDROID_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
TOOL      = arm-linux-androideabi
ARCHFLAGS = -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp
LINKFLAGS = -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
else
ifeq ($(ANDROID_ABI),x86)
TOOL      = i686-linux-android
ARCHFLAGS = -march=i686 -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse
else
ifeq ($(ANDROID_ABI),x86_64)
TOOL      = x86_64-linux-android
ARCHFLAGS = -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse
else
ifeq ($(ANDROID_ABI),arm64-v8a)
TOOL      = aarch64-linux-android
ARCHFLAGS = -march=armv8-a
else
$(error Invalid ABI specified in ANDROID_ABI)
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif

#
# Define Tools
#
CC      = $(TOOL)-clang
CXX     = $(TOOL)-clang++
LINK    = $(CXX)
STRIP   = $(TOOL)-strip
LIB     = $(TOOL)-ar -cr
RANLIB  = $(TOOL)-ranlib
SHLIB   = $(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(notdir $@) -o $@
SHLIBLN = $(POCO_BASE)/build/script/shlibln
DEP     = $(POCO_BASE)/build/script/makedepend.gcc
SHELL   = sh
RM      = rm -rf
CP      = cp
MKDIR   = mkdir -p

#
# Extension for Shared Libraries
#
SHAREDLIBEXT     = .so.$(target_version)
SHAREDLIBLINKEXT = .so

#
# Compiler and Linker Flags
#
CFLAGS          = $(ARCHFLAGS) -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing
CFLAGS32        =
CFLAGS64        =
CXXFLAGS        = $(ARCHFLAGS) -std=c++11 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -frtti -fexceptions
CXXFLAGS32      =
CXXFLAGS64      =
LINKFLAGS      += 
LINKFLAGS32     =
LINKFLAGS64     =
STATICOPT_CC    = 
STATICOPT_CXX   = 
STATICOPT_LINK  = -static
SHAREDOPT_CC    = 
SHAREDOPT_CXX   = 
SHAREDOPT_LINK  = -Wl,-rpath,$(LIBPATH)
DEBUGOPT_CC     = -g -D_DEBUG
DEBUGOPT_CXX    = -g -D_DEBUG
DEBUGOPT_LINK   = -g
RELEASEOPT_CC   = -O3 -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer
RELEASEOPT_CXX  = -O2 -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer
RELEASEOPT_LINK = -O2

#
# System Specific Flags
#
SYSFLAGS = -DPOCO_ANDROID -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY

#
# System Specific Libraries
#
SYSLIBS  = -lstdc++ -lsupc++
```

When I try to build it I get multiple occurrences of this error:

```
In file included from src/OpenSSLInitializer.cpp:15:
In file included from include/Poco/Crypto/OpenSSLInitializer.h:21:
include/Poco/Crypto/Crypto.h:30:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
...
In file included from src/X509Certificate.cpp:15:
In file included from include/Poco/Crypto/X509Certificate.h:21:
include/Poco/Crypto/Crypto.h:30:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
...
```

As I said earlier I use poco version 1.9.0, clang version 3.8.0 on linux machine. Build without Crypto modul works fine.
Thanks for help

Comment: It looks like it needs OpenSSL to build. Did you build OpenSSL beforehand?

Comment: I have not. When i build poco directly for linux it is not needed. How to do it? Where to position it?

Comment: https://github.com/ph4r05/android-openssl is one project that allows you to compile OpenSSL for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Solve by adding statically builded openssl library to configuration of poco

```
./configure --no-sharedmemory --no-wstring --config=Android-armeabi-v7a-clang --no-samples --no-tests --include-path=./openssl/Android/armeabi-v7a/include/--omit=Data,PageCompiler,ApacheConnector,CppParser,PDF,PocoDoc,ProGen,Encodings,CppUnit,MongoDB,Redis,SevenZip,Zip
```